# Ubuntu restarts when connecting second monitor

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors

Randomly after the weekend I started experiencing issues with having two monitors connected; one is connected to the GPU and the other to the CPU (only one slot in the GPU). They have been working fine for two weeks but then the monitor connected through the GPU stopped showing images and was coloured with random pixels. I restarted the computer and they were both working, however switched orientation - the left computer virtually was the right computer physically.

Using the Display menu in Ubuntu caused the monitor connected through the GPU to fail, and Ubuntu would restart (and the issue wouldn't be fixed).

I reinstalled Ubuntu but wiped and reformatted only the / partition, however the issue persists.

Issue the issue likely a result of the GPU? I.e. not having the right drivers or something?

Edit: spelling

Comment: Can you post what GPU you have and its installed drivers?

Comment: @Jeff My GPU is Radeon HD 8570 / R7 240/340 OEM and `lshw` outputs that the driver is radeon.

Comment: I have a 2 monitor Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS / Nvidia system that randomly resets or freezes at intervals ranging from hours to a day. I have swapped out everything including the case. The longest run I had was 3 days when I disconnected the 2nd Dell 1704FP monitor. And it was me that rebooted after 3 days enabling the 2nd monitor. Then that eventually froze the PC. I swapped out the Dell 1704FP for another and the PC eventually froze again. I'm on my 3rd and last Dell 1704FP and am still experiencing freezes. Is the the Dell monitors? Or maybe the Linux/Nvidia drivers can not handle 2 monitors?